# APNS and GAE java java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission modifyThreadGroup)

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, apple-push-notifications

Implementing the Apple Push Notification service on GAE. Gives me the following exception on local eclipse and when deployed.

Please help, what am I missing here ... the following is stack trace and source code.

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission modifyThreadGroup)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:374)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:301)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkAccess(DevAppServerFactory.java:326)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(ThreadGroup.java:299)
    at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:336)
    at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:422)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl$1MonitoringThread.<init>(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:95)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl.monitorSocket(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:116)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl.socket(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:140)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:160)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsServiceImpl.push(ApnsServiceImpl.java:46)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.AbstractApnsService.push(AbstractApnsService.java:52)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsServiceImpl.push(ApnsServiceImpl.java:36)
    at com.aaaaa.PushQuoteServlet.sendPushNotification(PushQuoteServlet.java:183)
    at com.aaaaa.PushQuoteServlet.getParameters(PushQuoteServlet.java:133)
    at com.aaaaa.PushQuoteServlet.doPost(PushQuoteServlet.java:88)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:369)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doDirectServerRequest(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:352)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:115)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:438)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Source code is:(It throws the exception at service.push)

```
ServletContext context = getServletContext();//
InputStream inputStream = context.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/aaaaa.p12");
//get list of device tokens from Database   
ArrayList<String> device = new ArrayList<String>();
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Query query = new Query("Tokens") ;
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(query) ;
Iterable<Entity> results = pq.asIterable() ;
for(Entity result:results){
String token = (String) result.getProperty("TokenValue");
device.add(token) ;
}
try{
    String client = device.get(0);
    ApnsService service = APNS.newService() .withCert(inputStream,         "password").withProductionDestination().withNoErrorDetection().build();
    String payload = APNS.newPayload().alertBody("Hello").badge(1).build();
    service.push(client, payload);
}catch (Exception e) {  
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);  
}
```

Thank you